# Mongodb: how to return a list of number of string?

Tags: mongodb

I just want to return a list of number or string as show a list on the screen, but if mongodb always return list objects, I have to loop on all the items

Sample data:

```
[{
  name: 'A',
}, {
  name: 'B'
}]
```

How to return only:

```
[
  'A',
  'B'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregate framework with `$group` and `$project`, you will get the array and then extract the array by property.

Working [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VLHpDa3MwH-)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "names": {
        "$push": "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      names: 1
    }
  }
])
```